# How to combine two fields and flag them accordingly

Tags: sql, string-concatenation

I would like to know how to flag customers who did not purchase some items that are described by two fields (product name and product number). I was able to perform this query for customers that did purchase them, but not the opposite. Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is part of my SQL query.

```
Select customer_id, product_name, product_number
from table 
where 
((PRODUCT_NAME = 'LIAM' AND PRODUCT_NUMBER = '212') OR
 (PRODUCT_NAME = 'ARRAY' AND PRODUCT_NUMBER = '325') 
)
```

Here is an example:

```
1 LIAM 212

1 STACY 452

1 NEIL 789

1 LIAM 345

2 ROSE 234

2 LIAM 345

2 ARRAY 325

3 STACY 452 

3 ARRAY 625
```

Query Result:

```
1 ARRAY 325

2 LIAM 212

3 ARRAY 325

3 LIAM 212
```

Comment: Likely you can use `not exists(...)`; also you could use `product_number in (...)` to make your conditions clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. There are more than 100 possibilities and the product name is not necessarily ARRAY for all.

Comment: Please can you provide sample data here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ and post it in your question. This will help us understanding your data and to answer it quicker. :)

Comment: Done. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You seems want `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.customer_id = t.customer_id and 
                        t1.PRODUCT_NAME in ('LIAM', 'ARRAY')
                 );
```

I don't see any advantage using of both `Product_name` and `Product_number` in the `where` clause if they are defined unique in table.

By this way, you will get customer's who never purchased `liam` or `array` product.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Product_name and Product_number are not defined unique in the table.